# looping a set of 3 functions in jquery - simple no?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Forgive my stupidity, I am new to jquery!

At the moment I have 3 functions

```
function function1(){
do something
}

function function2(){
do something
}

function function3(){
do something
}
```

What I want is to have on DOM load, for it to start function1, let the animation run in function 1. Once it has finished for it to load function 2, let the animation run, and once finished load function 3. then back to function 1 again.

Comment: Please include a simplified version of your "animation" code so we can see how you're doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your animations you have an `complete` parameter, you can just pass them in:

```
function function1(){
  $(...).animate(args, {
    complete: function2
  });
}

function function2(){
  $(...).animate(args, {
    complete: function3
  });
}

function function3(){
  $(...).animate(args, {
    complete: function1
  });
}

$(function1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [callback functions](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#complete).

```
function function1(){
    $(el).animate({...}, function2);
}

function function2(){
    $(el).animate({...}, function3);
}

function function3(){
    $(el).animate({...});
}
```